# Extract value using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is:'input type="hidden" value="5999" id="productPrice"'

I want to extract value from this string. Please help me to write regex for this.

Comment: I know I'm not willing to bang my head against the wall to check this.

Comment: No need for a regex, just use DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var string = '<input type="hidden" value="5999" id="productPrice">';

var regex = /<input type="hidden" value="([^"]+)" id="productPrice"/gi;
var price = regex.exec(string);

console.log(price[1]);

price[1];
```